# Why couldn't I add a costume view to LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I'm struggling for past hours adding a simple custome view to a LinearLayout. I found several solutions on SO but most answers are relatively incomplete, giving layout model alternatives, working for OPs but not for me, etc. I'm not an android developer rather developing some apps for once a while. I really need some help here.

The View class

```
package com.android2d.supportclass;
public class Shapes extends View {
    Paint paint;

    public Shapes(Context context) {
        super(context);
  }
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  ..
   ..

    }
  }
```

The Activity

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new Shapes(this));
      
    }
```

They work just fine (without that activity_main.xml). But now If I modify it, creating  that activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".a0_5_PercobaanWithSpaces">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.android2d.supportclass.Shapes
                    android:id="@+id/mview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and modifying my Activity to

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)     
 
}
```

Then the app runs but nothing from the custome class shows up. It's supposed to be easy, isn't it? What could be my mistakes?

Comment: You need the rest of the `View` constructors to be implemented in `Shapes`, notably the two-parameter one.

Comment: @CommonsWare. Ok . I remembered those other constructors from the answers somewhere on this site. I'll implement them later and report to you. I'm taking a break. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't show all the code for your custom view but, I believe the fundamental problem is that you don't have code that measures your view. When you use the view to set the content, it is filling the screen since it is the top level view. Once you place it into a *LinearLayout* and specify `wrap_content`, you will have to tell the layout how big your custom view wants to be. (A quick test of this is to explicitly set the width and height of the view in the XML, say a height of `500dp`.)

There are many resources online about how to write custom views. [here](https://medium.com/@quiro91/custom-view-mastering-onmeasure-a0a0bb11784d) is one that discusses measuring custom views.

You should also specify constraints for all direct children of *ConstraintLayout* and avoid using `match_parent` since its use is discouraged.

Comment: HI i think that's the problem. Sort of measuring views. Like "It's already there but the view size, constraints, etc. prohibited it from being seen". But I haven't got time to fully investigate it (kinda busy) so for now hold on . +1 for now.